# WhereHas on relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I'm trying to query a `client` on a relationship I have setup.

It's a 1 - 1 relationship in that a `client_valuation` has one client.

Client Valuation table contains a `client_id` column and the clients table contains an `id`. Relationship is working fine.

I have a search form setup at the top of my page, which pass a get request containing a "q" parameter. When that q is set, I want to run a query that also calls the clients table to query the client_name.

Not been able to do this as of yet.

**My Controller** is as follows :

```
$valuations = ClientValuation::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->whereHas('client', function ($query) use ($request)
    {
        $query->where('client_name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
    })
    ->when($request->input('q'), function($query) use ($request)
    {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('client_valuation_street', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
        });
    })
    ->paginate(20);

return view('backend.client_valuations.index',
    [
        'valuations'    => $valuations,
        'pageTitle'     => 'Market Valuations'
    ]);
```

The controller returns 0 results every time.

**Client Valuations Model**

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client', 'client_id', 'client_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want an `OR` between your two condition.

```
$valuations = ClientValuation::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->whereHas('client', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('client_name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
    })
    ->orWhere('client_valuation_street', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%')
    ->paginate(20);

return view('backend.client_valuations.index',
    [
        'valuations'    => $valuations,
        'pageTitle'     => 'Market Valuations'
    ]);
```

By the way, the `when()` doesn't do much since you're using `$request->input('q')` in the client name condition too. Unless you want to put both inside the `when()` method.

```
$valuations = ClientValuation::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->when($request->input('q'), function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereHas('client', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('client_name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
        })
        ->orWhere('client_valuation_street', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
    })
    ->paginate(20);

return view('backend.client_valuations.index',
    [
        'valuations'    => $valuations,
        'pageTitle'     => 'Market Valuations'
    ]);
```

Comment: @StuBlackett if it suits your question, dont forget to set it as the correct answer

Comment: I will do @N69S - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `foreign_key` in your model, so edit it like this:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client::class');
}
```

And in your controller use this relation:

```
$valuations = ClientValuation::with('client')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereHas('client', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('client_name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
        })
        ->when($request->input('q'), function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('client_valuation_street', 'like', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
            });
        })
        ->paginate(20);

    return view('backend.client_valuations.index',
        [
            'valuations'    => $valuations,
            'pageTitle'     => 'Market Valuations'
        ]);
```

Probably you don't need return in your when. But try like this and provide errors here to solve this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @N69S's answer worked a treat. I figured I needed an orWhere somewhere